# Создание Skip List, используя STL

Tags: stl, c++

Кто-нибудь когда-то встречался с подобной реализацией скип списка?
Рассматривал варианты реализации с помощью vector и set.
Но возникают затруднения с переходом между уровнями, так как индексы для каждого уровня будут свои.

o---> o------------------------------------------------------------------> o    Top level
 o---> o-----------------> o----------> o-------------------------------> o    Level 3
 o---> o----------> o---> o----------> o-------------------------------> o    Level 2
 o---> o---> o---> o---> o---> o---> o---> o---> o---> o---> o---> o    Bottom level

Head  1st   2nd   3rd   4th   5th   6th   7th   8th   9th   10th  NIL
      Node  Node  Node  Node  Node  Node  Node  Node  Node  Node

Похоже, вопрос просто переезжает [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/378674/c-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-stl-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: https://github.com/petegoodliffe/skip_list

Comment: Возможно, я нуб, но у меня не получилось открыть его проект, который в папке build. Судя по описанию, я понял, что это не "скип список, реализованный с помощью stl", а "скип список как stl".

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, википедия уже не авторитетный источник:) Первая же [ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) (код на самом деле в самом конце, он просто немного скрыт, но он на с++ с темплейтами).

Comment: Только вот там не используется STL, тогда как мне нужно именно с STL.

Comment: там полным ходом используется STL. Возможно, Вы просто не знаете, что такое STL или вкладываете в это что то другое.

Comment: Набор согласованных обобщённых алгоритмов, контейнеров. Контейнеры: vector, set, map...
В том коде я их не вижу.
В чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Там есть контейнер vector, который красиво зашифровался под Array. Там активно используются итераторы. Да, похоже код не совсем рабочий (бывает, выкладывают люди и такое, но может быть это маководы).

Я думаю, что это самая что не наесть STL реализация.

Да и писать на базе stl контейнер, который потом не сможет работать с другими stl алгоритмами - моветон. Поэтому `"скип список как stl"` - это хорошая идея.

Comment: Дело в том, что я уже написал скип список с помощью указателей, теперь мне нужно переделать его под STL.

Comment: Тогда наверное правильно выложить реализацию и, скорее всего получите рекомендации, как его переписать, использую STL.

Comment: Меня интересует только один вопрос, который относится скорее просто к STL.
У меня есть два вектора, которые содержат структуры. Допустим, в первом векторе значения 1, 4, во втором: 1, 2, ..., 6. Мне нужно идти по первому вектору, когда дойду до конца, спуститься "на один уровень ниже" и продолжить проход по вектору. Для этого мне нужно засунуть в структуру указатель на другой элемент вектора. Ок. Но потом нужно продолжить проход с того же значения, хотя индекс уже будет другой. Вопрос: как это сделать?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю проблемы. Но то, что раньше у Вас было указателями, теперь просто станет итераторами. Соответственно, если нужно вернуться на уровень выше - сохраните итератор перед проваливанием.