# Переход между элементами STL списка

Tags: c++, stl, std-list

Как можно, не используя итератор begin() и end(), двигаться в списке? Нужно просто next. Судя по описанию, то там нет просто next() итератора.
Как можно с центра списка передвинуться дальше?

Вот нашел по теме [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409396) с использованием массива и функции sizeof, только вот не получается применить пока.

На примере, что хочу.

```
list<int> l;
l.push_back(1);
l.push_back(2);
l.push_back(3);
```

Нужно вывести со второго.

Comment: Есть ещё rbegin и rend:) плюс есть куча алгоритмов, которые позволяют перебирать элемены контейнера без явного использования итераторов.

Comment: rbegin и rend - это все заставляет задействовать начало или конец.
Получается, перейти просто к следующему никак?

Comment: Надо размер листа (l.size()) поделить пополам - так вы найдете центр и потом отступить от него, сколько вам нужно. И делаеться это обычно с помощью итератора (list<int>::iterator).

Comment: А теперь такой поворот: мне нужно реализовать скип-список с помощью STL.
Когда я спускаюсь на 1 уровень, я просто нахожусь на позиции некоторого элемента (возможно, слева где-то, может, по центру, а может, и справа). Т.е. есть ссылка. Перехожу по ней. Далее нужно двигаться дальше по списку, не зная точной позиции.

Comment: next, prev нет, зато у многих итераторов есть инкремент / декремент

Answer (score 2):

С++11 позволяет следующее:

```
for (auto& element : elements)
{
//    element делать что-то
}
```

Где elements - любой контейнер, поддерживающий как раз методы begin() и end(). Т.е. использование их в неявном виде все равно имеет место.

А вообще не понятно, речь идет о синтаксисе, или какой-то урезанной реализации std::list, у которой нет begin() и end(), у нее должен быть другой способ установить итератор в начало и конец...

Если это вопрос с собеседования (а абсурдность его наводит на такую мысль), то, наверное, они пытались выяснить, насколько хорошо Вы знаете внутреннее устройство контейнера, и, возможно, знаете, где точно в памяти будет располагаться первый элемент, и сможете проинициализировать итератор таким образом, а дальше уже двигать его через operator++. Возможно :)
В таком случае, имхо, правильный ответ: реализации STL бывают разные, это является большой проблемой совместимости, например, экспорта данных между разными библиотеками, но Вы предполагаете, что очевидная реализация связного списка - где сам список и есть первый элемент + служебная информация (указатель на последний элемент, длина, какие-то еще данные/методы). Или получить информацию о первом и последнем элементе можно в "служебной информации", которая и будет представлять собой объект list.

Comment: Глобальная цель - реализация скип списка, но именно с использованием stl. Суть заключается в том, что, проходя по верхнему уровню, програма быстрее дойдет до нужного.

Comment: @theStigger, если у Вас есть итератор, то переход к следующему элементу через оператор++

Comment: @TheStigger1, а чем это (https://github.com/petegoodliffe/skip_list), или множество других готовых реализаций не устраивают?)

Comment: Судя по описанию, я так понял, что это не "скип список, реализованный с помощью stl", а "скип список как stl".

Comment: @TheStigger1, в Интернете полно реализаций, многие из них так или иначе используют STL. И реализация по ссылке использует STL.

Answer (score 2):

[Функция advance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/)

Comment: Но будьте предельно внимательны. Использование std::advance может негативно сказаться на производительности вашей программы. Конкретнее - она предназначена для работы с контейнерами, которые имеют итератор произвольного доступа (вектор, дек). Как известно двунаправленный список std::list таких итераторов не содержит и вызов std::advance будет занимать линейное время от к-во айтемов O(N)